# How to enable exception generation in MySqlDataAdapter?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms, mariadb

When I use the MysqlDataAdapter.Update method, no exceptions are generated.

I read that I should set the adapter.ContinueUpdateOnError property to false, but it doesn't work.
Here's my implementation of the method:

```
public static void ChangingStatusOfExportedCodes(DataTable dataTable, string date)
        {
            try
            {
                using (MySqlConnection conn = DbUtils.GetDBConnection())
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        adapter.UpdateCommand = new MySqlCommand(
                            $"UPDATE codes SET status = '3' " +
                            $"WHERE gtin = @gtin " +
                            $"AND (date_print BETWEEN @startTime AND @endTime) " +
                            $"AND status = '2'",
                            conn);
                        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startTime", Convert.ToDateTime(date));
                        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endTime", Convert.ToDateTime(date).AddDays(1));

                        //adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
                        var parameter = new MySqlParameter("@gtin", MySqlDbType.UInt64)
                        {
                            SourceColumn = "gtin"
                        };
                        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);

                        parameter = new MySqlParameter("@datePrint", MySqlDbType.DateTime)
                        {
                            SourceColumn = "date_print"
                        };
                        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                        
                        adapter.UpdateCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.OutputParameters;
                        adapter.UpdateBatchSize = 1;
                        adapter.ContinueUpdateOnError = false;
                        adapter.Update(dataTable);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```